# Would it be wrong to copy-paste questions from Quora?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

Since Quora just went public, I decided to have a look around and found certain topics like Gmail that contained questions that would be great for the Web Apps SE-site.

However, would it be considered plagiarism if I simply asked the same questions on the new site?

Edit: I would only look at the titles for an interesting question to ask, so if I write my own question body, it's not plagiarism in the real sense of the word. However, it's probably not really polite since if we are better indexed or have a better PageRank, we would steal some of their attention.

In response to Jeff's answer: how should I attribute to the sites? Simply mention I found this question on Quora and link to it?

Comment: Also note the questions on Quora about us! (http://www.quora.com/Stack-Overflow?q=stac)

Answer (score 12):

We don't support plagiarism from this or any other site.

However, it is fair use to quote and attribute content in general, from any public website -- including ours!

Answer (score 6):

The thing about questions is that there's only a few conceivable ways to ask them. I don't think someone is a plagiarist simply because they asked a question in writing that has been asked before somewhere else.

I wouldn't start copying questions verbatim one after another .. but you have to find inspiration somewhere to seed a site :) (Inspiration being the operative word).