# Response and voting on answers copied and pasted, and from a website which has questionable credibility

Tags: support, plagiarism

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510094/securely-creating-and-destroying-login-sessions-in-php/15613294?noredirect=1#comment22174521_15613294) a user copied and pasted code from an article written by someone else. I believe it is unfair to vote the answer up since copying and pasting code/text isn't really doing any work. What do others think about up voting or down voting? I believe in some situations it's ok, no need to reinvent the wheel, but in this situation the source doesn't elaborate well and I think the poster could have at least explained better. Also copying from wikihow and not saying that's where it's coming from isn't (in my opinion) a reliable source. Are some sources more acceptable  to copy from than others?

UPDATE: the answer has since been removed

Answer (score 6):

[You are allowed to quote external sources](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54559/169187) providing you credit the original source. Especially in this case when the answer violates Wikihow's [terms of use](http://www.wikihow.com/wikiHow:Terms-of-Use). It doesn't have to be a reliable source (this is not Wikipedia) -- up- and downvotes determine  whether it's a good answer or not.

I say either edit the answer to add a link to the original source and downvote, or flag for moderator attention.

---

I did some digging and it seems many of the user's answers are copy-pasted without attribution:

- First part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564208/delete-folder-dynamically-using-php-script/15564277#15564277) *(deleted)* copied from http://sysblogd.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/delete-folder-recursively-via-php-if-ftp-says-prohibited-directory-name/ and the second from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817628)
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545685/how-to-find-center-point-of-two-latitude-longitude/15545865#15545865) copied from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vemapcontroldev/thread/1589f19c-b32b-4c09-a1c3-b82e4d589ac6
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177274/remove-auto-added-p-from-a-page-that-has-no-literal-content-uses-shortcodes/15495401#15495401) copied from [an answer from wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7848)
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319518/formatting-error-while-publishing-the-blog-from-microsoft-word/15495208#15495208) copied from http://www.thewebsiteprofessionals.com/wordpress-paragraph-tags.html
- The code of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493769/is-there-a-way-to-tell-curl-to-not-use-cache/15494092#15494092) copied from http://www.php.net/function.curl-setopt#82300
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356891/facebook-graph-api-pagination-is-not-giving-the-excat-result/15409665#15409665) copied from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10575022)

There are probably more, I didn't go through all the answers. Many are also link-only. He also seems to have a habit of pressuring people to accept his answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564100/after-30-days-from-specified-date-in-php/15564134#15564134), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544980/the-bug-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-date-diff-in/15545155#15545155)).

I don't think it's malicious, he just doesn't know he shouldn't be doing it. He would probably stop it if a moderator notified him. (I'll also comment with a link to this in one of his answers. *EDIT:* He deleted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564208/delete-folder-dynamically-using-php-script/15564277#15564277) (10k+) where I added the comment.)

Answer (score 6):

Not only is copying and pasting code/text not really doing any work, but copying and pasting code/text *without linking to the source* is wrong. Although the answer contains a wikiHow link, that's a link to a different article:

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Managment-System-in-Php-and-Mysql

The article from which the user has copied is not referenced at all:

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Not only that, but his answer, before the latest edit, was something *entirely different* yet probably just as unhelpful: a full code dump seemingly from nowhere.

Based on the fact that he has simply copied and pasted without so much as a proper reference, as well as his response to your comment on his answer which shows me he doesn't really want to take himself seriously, I deleted the answer altogether.